# Why is Stack Overflow successful?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do we prefer Stack Overflow to other programming sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20549/why-do-we-prefer-stack-overflow-to-other-programming-sites)

I agree with [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14665/reasons-why-stackoverflow-is-amazing) that the site is very good. My main interest is, why the site is successful?

Possible answers might be:

1. People like to get rated?
2. People like to help other people?

What do you think?

Comment: @Henk Holterman, i think, only us dutch guys have other associations with that word ;-).

Comment: can you suggest another word?

Answer (score 4):

Both.

People like to help others and they like a reward.

A side effect of the reputation system is that the site is mostly self regulated. More users mean more users with mod powers. And more users to help new users to become good/valuable users.

Answer (score 4):

Also, one of the primary reasons is that it *isn't* experts-exchange. No scrolling to the bottom of the page to see answers, like one does at ee, also no monthly fee like at ee.

Comment: And no double-entendre in the website name like ExpertSexChange.